# Combine Room and Retroffit with Dagger2

Tags: android, retrofit2, dao, dagger-2, android-room

What the proper way to create DAO with Room and Retrofit?

I have database module like this:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationDatabaseModule {

private final String mDatabaseName;
ApplicationDatabase mApplicationDatabase;

public ApplicationDatabaseModule(@ApplicationContext Context context, Class<? extends ApplicationDatabase> roomDataBaseClass, String databaseName) {
    mDatabaseName = databaseName;
    mApplicationDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, roomDataBaseClass, mDatabaseName).build();
}

@Singleton
@Provides
ApplicationDatabase provideApplicationDatabase() {
    return mApplicationDatabase;
}

@Singleton
@Provides
CitiesDao provideCitiesDao() {
    return mApplicationDatabase.getCitiesDao();
}

}
```

POJO class like this:

```
@Entity
public class City {

@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
private int cityId;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
private String cityName;

public int getCityId() {
    return cityId;
}

public void setCityId(int cityId) {
    this.cityId = cityId;
}

public String getCityName() {
    return cityName;
}

public void setCityName(String cityName) {
    this.cityName = cityName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "City [cityId = " + cityId + ", cityName = " + cityName + "]";
}
}
```

DAO interface like this:

```
@Dao
public interface CitiesDao {

@Insert
void insertCities(City... cities);

@Query("SELECT * FROM City")
City[] queryCities();

}
```

And API for Retrofit:

```
public interface CitiesApi {
@GET("/api/cities")
Call<City[]> requestCities();
}
```

As I know DAO is responsible for accessing data, including data passed through REST-client. But these two parts are represented by interfaces and built into separate classes. What is the proper way to implement DAO?

Comment: check my sample app that illustrates that: https://github.com/mtangoo/Kasuku-Muvi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DAO is responsible for accessing data

yes

> , including data passed through REST-client.

God no

> What is the proper way to implement DAO?

Room already generates a proper way of implementation for your DAO based on your interface + annotations, I think it's called `CitiesDao_Impl`.

> What the proper way to create DAO with Room and Retrofit?

Room doesn't know about Retrofit and shouldn't need to know about Retrofit. It only cares about local data persistence.

Meaning your DAO needs to look like this:

```
@Dao
public interface CitiesDao {

    @Insert
    @Transaction
    void insertCities(City... cities);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM City")
    LiveData<List<City>> queryCities();

}
```

So what you *actually* need is a Worker that will fetch new data in background when either cache is invalid (force fetch new data) or when your sync task should run (for example when device is charging and you are on WIFI and you're at 2 AM to 7 AM -- for this you'd need `WorkManager`).

Immediately fetching new data though is fairly easy, all you need is either an AsyncTask in a singleton context that returns `null` from `doInBackground`, or your own Executor that you post your background task to.

```
 public class FetchCityTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     ...

     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         List<City> cities = citiesApi.requestCities().execute().body(); // TODO error handling
         citiesDao.insertCities(cities);
         return null;
     }
 }
```

And then

```
new FetchCityTask(...).execute();
```

Now when this task runs, your UI will be updated with latest data by observing the LiveData that you store in a ViewModel.

```
public class CitiesViewModel
        extends ViewModel {
    private final CitiesDao citiesDao;

    private LiveData<List<City>> liveResults;

    public CitiesViewModel(...) {
        ...
        liveResults = citiesDao.queryCities();
    }

    public LiveData<List<City>> getCities() {
        return liveResults;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    CitiesViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CitiesViewModel.class, ...);

    ...
    viewModel.getTasks().observe(getViewLifecycle(), list -> {
        //noinspection Convert2MethodRef
        listAdapter.submitList(list);
    });
}
```

Comment: how to import WorkManager into project? `import androidx.work.WorkManager;` can not find `work` package.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a repository class to handle your data. Then you simply interact with your repository. Some pseudocode for you:

```
class Repository {
   private CitiesDao localSource;
   private CitiesApi remoteSource;

   public Repository() {
       //initialize objects here
   }

   City[] getCities() {
       if (networkIsAvailable) {
           City[] cities = remoteSource.requestCities();
           saveCitiesToDatabase(cities);
           return cities;
       } else {
           return localSource.queryCities();
       }
   }

   private void saveCitiesToDatabase(City[] cities) {
    //TODO save cities to databse
   }

}
```